# Why does the main thread stop every time

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

I have a question about the main thread in my application, which I debug using Visual Studio. While the application is running, what I see in the input window is that the main thread stops, every time.

So my question is: Why does the main thread stop every time and the application continues running

The input window give me the following:

```
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\mscorlib.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'c:\documents and settings\administrateur\bureau\gestiondesimmobilisations machi howa hada\gestiondesimmobilisations\bin\debug\GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' chargé, symboles chargés.
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Windows.Forms.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Drawing.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Data.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Xml.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Core.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Xml.Linq.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'c:\program files\microsoft sql server compact edition\v3.5\devices\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'System.SR.dll' chargé
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'System.SR.resources.dll' chargé
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
'GestionDesImmobilisations.exe' (Managé) : 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll' chargé


Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
Le thread 0xf7137ee6 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What kind of application do you have? Can you show some code?

Comment: Can you give more detail about what mean you say stops.  If a UI thread of an application blocks, an app will become unresponsive, which is why any long running tasks should always be done on a background thread.  If a thread becomes deadlocked, it will block indefinitely.  Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: What makes you think the thread mentioned in the debug output is the **main** thread?

Comment: I think the __output__ window is showing you the end of some helper threads. Do you have an actual problem?  A stopped main-thread would be a problem.